# Is it ok to use HTTP GET method that modifies the DB for newsletter confirmation/unsubscribe mails?

Tags: web-applications, web, newsletter

I'm implementing a web app that gives the user the ability to subscribe to a "newsletter". Users only need to provide their email address, there is no signup page. To confirm the email address the system sends an email to the given address and asks the users to verify the email address by clicking a link. That links makes a GET requests to the servers and modifies a flag in the model that represents the user's newsletter from confirmed => false to confirmed => true. The problem is that I'm using a GET request that modifies the internal server state and this is bad. The thing is that all system that need email confirmation follow this pattern.

Is there a better way to do this? Should I use Javascript to trigger an Ajax POST request when the users enters the confirmation page in his browser?

Same applies for unsubscribes.

Thanks!

Comment: If you click on the link twice, do you get the same output the second time as the first time? Or do you get some kind of message that you've already confirmed? Or an error?

Comment: I get the same output. You could say that is idempotent

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a GET request for anything that isn't idempotent.  Use POST to subscribe for the first time and to change an existing subscription record.  Technically, you could use PUT to alter an existing record, but you need to know the record exists already, so it's easier just to always use POST.

To be strict, you could use the GET link to pre-populate a form which you can use JS or a confirmation submit button the user could press on the page to trigger a POST request to your service.

Comment: Which leads to the question -- is this idempotent or not? If so, then it's fine. (We can't tell from the question.)

Comment: @David besides being idempotent, GET should generally not alter anything... it's generally best use PUT to modify resources when it's known to be in an idempotent manner

Comment: The only HTTP method that will work, standard across most email clients, is HTTP GET. In this case, one should probably throw away 'the book' and go for something that 'just works'.

Comment: @Ray: If you take that literally, it means GET shouldn't be logged, since that's an alteration.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz logging doesn't create or modify a resource exposed by a restful web service (usually).

Comment: @Ray Same here. The resource modified (a newsletter subscription) is not exposed by the web service. The fact that the URL was accessed is recorded.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not sure I agree totally, but I see your point.  If the subscription record was created on filling out a form, then the email link sends a person to page and that fires a flag on the subscription record confirming the setting it might be like logging.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow (well, StackExchange) uses HTTP GET in their subscription confirmation emails. It's not a bad thing to do. In fact, I can't find a single instance of a site in my inbox/archive that does anything to the contrary.

https://stackexchange.com/filters/email-confirm/999999

Don't fret.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [interesting article](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=152805) regarding this issue.

What it says basically is:

- If a link does a request that alters things, "web accelerator"(i'm not sure if it's still a thing) might pre-fetch the page and does the alterations **without you even touching the link**.
- To prevent that, just implement a page with GET request, then use a Javascript to request POST/PUT to alter. This way, web accelerator won't fire anything and you actually have to visit the page by yourself by clicking the link.
- If Javascript is disabled, put a form in the page that does the POST/PUT.

This still sounds a bit sketchy as the POST/PUT request doesn't come from user's direct action. But then really we're requesting all kinda stuff in Javascript and most of them are indirect to user's behavior anyway.